# Where can I get TypeScript 1.0.3?

Tags: typescript

I see Typescript project has a 1.0.3 release branch. However, typescriptlang.org doesn't mention any way to download the release. Anyone know how to get it?

Comment: Isn't it installed with the latest Visual studio 2013 update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and i got Typescript 1.0.3.

I checked my version in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0` by running the following command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0>tsc -v
Version 1.0.3.0
```

Alternatively your best bet is to build it yourself from GitHub.

Comment: Just fyi, it is not on NPM

Answer (score 2):

If you use NPM (and have Git installed) you can just `npm install --saveDev git://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript.git#release-1.0.3` in your project folder.

Note that you may  prefer `release-1.1`, which fixes many bugs and is pretty stable.